# How to retrieve the summary of a JIRA ticket via REST API?

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am trying to write a shell script, that automates my workflow with JIRA. I aim for something like:

```
jira_flow start $KEY
```

The steps of the script shall be as follows:

- deploy current project to sonarqube
- create a new branch according to jira issue key and summary

Therefore I need a way to get the summary of an issue.

Firstly I tried using the `issue` API and `grep`.

```
curl http://jira.local:8081/rest/api/2/issue/$KEY | \
  json_pp | \
  grep sumarry

# produces:

    "summary" : "linked issue summary 1"
    "summary" : "linked issue summary 2"
  "summary" : "sub-task summary 1"
  "summary" : "sub-task summary 2"
  "summary" : "sub-task summary 3"
"summary" : "issue summary"
```

This approach gave me a lot of results, because it also prints the summaries of linked tickets and sub-tasks.

My second try was using the `search` API and limit the fields to retrieve. This approach failed because I was not able to search for an issue by its `key`.

```
curl http://jira.local:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=key=$KEY

# returns:

no matches found: http://jira.local/rest/api/2/search?jql=key=$KEY
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) to parse json and extract required field(s):

```
$ curl -s "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRASERVER-66213" | jq ".fields.summary"
"Ship with Java Option PrintConcurrentLocks by Default"
```

For your case just put correct URL.
You second approach didn't worked as the parameter for filtering fields is `field`:

```
curl -s "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRASERVER-66213?fields=summary" | jq "."


{                                                              
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",                              
  "id": "874745",                                              
  "self": "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/874745",
  "key": "JRASERVER-66213",                                    
  "fields": {                                                  
    "summary": "Ship with Java Option PrintConcurrentLocks by Default"                                                         
  }                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have/want jq then you can grep with the `P` and `o` flags.

```
 curl -s "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/JRASERVER-66213" | grep -Po '"summary":.*?[^\\]"
```

> "summary":"Ship with Java Option PrintConcurrentLocks by Default"

Comment: This approach does not work in the scenario, I described. Try it for the issue `TRANS-2459`. This will yield multiple lines of summary, due to linked issues.

Comment: Just add the 'm' flag set to 1?

Answer (score -1):

Use  this:

```
curl -s https://<JiraServer>.jira.com/rest/api/2/search?jql="< JQL >+"&fields=id,key,summary,description,issuetype";
```

Comment: Could you provide a real world example? How would I use this api for https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/TRANS-2459 ?